# Android Studio | How to display Emojis in RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-studio, emoji

So I'm trying to display Emojis in `ImageView` and list them in `RecyclerView`. So far I only found that it's possible to display Emoji in `TextView` but I need it in `ImageView`, please help.

EDIT:

I just found an SVG library by https://sensa.co/emoji/ it's 349 emojis in SVG/PNG, the folder size is about 6MB and the single emoji size is the standard icon size 24x24 dp. but I hope to find a way to consume as little space as possible to make the app's overall size small.

Answer (score 0):

Why only ImageView is needed? The most lightweight variant is RecyclerView with TextView's.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).